# Are there differences in graphics between the Xbox 360 and Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, rise-of-the-tomb-raider

Is there a noticeable graphics and lag difference between Rise of Tomb Raider on the Xbox 360 in comparison to the Xbox One?

I'd rather not buy an Xbox One if I can just play it on the Xbox 360. My concern is the game will will lag significantly in graphically intensive areas. If I am in an intense combat situation, I do not want to put up with the game lagging while I am being shot at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's pretty smooth on 360:

[Digital Foundry](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-2015-rise-of-the-tomb-raider-face-off)

> This time we have the talented bunch at Nixxes taking point on the Xbox 360 port and the results are remarkable. This is the same game that we enjoyed on Xbox One with nips and tucks made in all of the expected places. It lacks much of the visual panache of the next-gen version, but it's still an attractive title and a worthy sequel. It doesn't feel like an afterthought at all - it's a project that has received a lot of care and attention.
>
> In fact, there is a strong argument that in one sense at least, the
>   Xbox 360 game is actually more playable than its current-gen sibling.
>   On Xbox One, we complained about input latency and its impact on the
>   game experience(...) Moving to Xbox 360, we were stunned to discover
>   that this same issue does not exist on Microsoft's older console to
>   anything like the same extent.
>
> In fact, Rise of the Tomb Raider feels significantly more responsive
>   here on Xbox 360

Looks like you chose the correct game NOT to move into next-gen

Comment: The article actually clearly states that there are visual differences. Hence, if that is the only concern, a move should be advised. Furthermore, updating the controller will likely get rid of the input lag the article complained about. Without a clear statement, this point should be considered with care. Note that input lag is different from FPS induced lag.